# Comparing dates in a specific format

Tags: bash, date

I have to compare (greater than) two dates formatted as 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'. For instance: 30/11/2015 14:24:35.
I've tried to convert them to timestamp and then compare each other. But the attempt to convert to timestamp wasn't successful.

```
$ date --date='16/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%s"
date: invalid date `16/12/2012 07:21:22'
```

How can I do that (directly, or converting to timestamp, or using another solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to re-order the fields.

For example, with sed and bash:

```
date="$(sed -re 's_(..)/(..)/(....) _\3-\2-\1 _' <<<"$date")"
```

Once you have them in big-endian form, you can do the comparison lexically - there's no longer any need to convert to epoch seconds.  According to the Bash man page, its built-in `test` (but not `/usr/bin/test`) can compare strings with `'<'` and `'>'`.  Remember that they need quotes, so as not to be misinterpreted as redirections!